# CloudFormation placement group partition count

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create and specify partitions for placement groups in a CloudFormation template. I tried creating resources like:

```
"PlacementGroup" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::PlacementGroup",
  "Properties" : {
  "Strategy" : "partition",
  "PartitionCount": 3
  }
}
```

But partition count, only seems to be available in the CLI and AWS Console. The same applies for EC2 CF properties; PartitionNumber does not seem to be available in CF, only in the CLI and AWS Console.

Has anyone else run across this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The `Partition Count` parameter is **missing in CloudFormation**.

I performed an experiment and created a Partition Placement Group via the AWS CLI without specifying a Partition Count. It created a Placement Group with **2 partitions**.

So, if you want a Partition Placement Group with something other than 2 partitions, it looks like you'll need to find another way to create it -- either outside of the CloudFormation template, or by using a **Custom Resource** powered by an AWS Lambda function, which could make the correct API call for you.